# Spring MVC: update handlebars view without restart

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, handlebars.java

I am working on a Spring MVC web application (not spring boot). I develop it locally by building a war package using maven, and then running this application using tomcat.

The Spring application uses the `com.github.jknack.handlebars.springmvc.HandlebarsViewResolver` (from [handlebars.java](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java)) to render handlebars views, e.g. `index.hbs`.

Whenever I change one of these files, I need to restart the Spring application in order to see my changes in the browser. Is there a way, e.g. through some debug or development mode, for these updates to be picked up by Spring without a restart?